# Permissions regarding MODIFY CONTENTS for pdf output

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I have this line of code in my jrxml

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.encrypted" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.128.bit.key" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.user.password" value="test"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.permissions.allowed" value="SCREENREADER|PRINTING"/>
```

My question is, what kind of security do the modify contents does? I tried to edit my PDF in any online PDF writer and I can edit those contents

Comment: You should post small *jrxml* to reproduce the issue. BTW, what version of JR are you using?

Comment: jasper-5.6.1, may I know what is the means of PERMISSION.COPY? is it the highlighting the details of the PDF?

Comment: [What is net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.permissions.denied](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.permissions.denied)

Comment: Modified my line of code, do this list of permission will disallow pdf editing?